# Curry-Howard: Types with Logic vs Types as Logic

Tags: logic, category-theory, computer-science, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

In the paper [Knowledge Representation in Bicategories of Relations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.00526) there is a short remark on p47 that makes a distinction that seems quite far ranging regarding the Curry-Howard Correspondence. The paper is is interested in "types with logic" not "types as logic", where the first is sometimes called "two-level type theory", or "logic-enriched type theory".

[image: Remark from p 47 of "Knowledge Representation in Bicategories of relations"]

It cites Nicola Gambino and Peter Aczel 2006 paper [The generalised type-theoretic interpretation
of constructive set theory](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/27588436.pdf), which is difficult to read.

Is there a nice intuitive explanation of this distinction? (Something that would allow me to understand the gist of it, and know at what point I would need to dig into the details?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try these two posts by Mike Shulman, [Propositions as Some Types and Algebraic Nonalgebraicity](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/01/propositions_as_some_types_and.html)  and [Freedom From Logic](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/11/freedom_from_logic.html).